# WordPress Blog Website Loading too Slow

Tags: wordpress, web, loading

I have installed Latest WordPress on my website with CDN and cache plugin. But, it is loading too slow. It is taking around 2 minutes to load.

I have optimized database and images too. Still the problem is in place.

Please suggest solutions as soon as possible.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check your WordPress website not only by images and database. check also with w3c standard. It will show you the loading seconds and errors of code as per w3c standard.

To refer: [Link here](https://validator.w3.org/)

And you can optimize your images ,database, css and js by using htaccess

To use mod_deflate, 
ask your host to install it for you on your Apache server,
add these lines to your .htaccess file:

```
# BEGINNING of DEFLATE instructions
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xmlapplication/xhtml+xml text/css application/javascript
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent
# END of DEFLATE instruction
```

For optimization kindly click the:[Link here](http://www.asiteaboutnothing.net/c_website-optimization.html)

Comment: Hello Naveenkumar,

Your given guidelines have worked and resolved problem a bit next steps. Thanks for the sharing the details.

Now, website is loading fine from my network as well as outside.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Is it on a fast server? Best to send a message to the host and see if it's the server or your site. Then if it's the server, ask to be moved to a different one.

Which cache plugin do you use? I usually go for WP Cache and it speeds it up nicely.

Comment: That was meant to be a comment, not an answer. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Two minutes? Dang that's long! Or did you mean 2 seconds?

There are several things I would suggest you do:

1. **Check the performance of your plugins** with [P3 (Plugin Performance Profiler)](https://wordpress.org/plugins/p3-profiler/). This plugin will analyze the plugins you've installed to see if any are causing major slowdowns.
2. **Use some page speed analyzers** and see what improvements/suggestions they come up with. I like to use [GTmetrix](https://gtmetrix.com) which covers both Google and Yahoo, but do check [Google Page Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) separately as well, since GTmetrix doesn't cover mobile.
3. **Shop around the different cache plugins** and tweak the settings. I used to use W3 Total Cache but found that [WP Fastest Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-fastest-cache/) worked better for me. It can really depend on your site. Also make sure that your cache plugin is actually enabled, as many are not by default.

Good luck! Optimizing Wordpress can be a finicky business, but who doesn't love their site to be fast 0:-)

Comment: I have optimized contents through mod_deflate. Now, website is loading fine..As this problem has been resolved now...so good to go and close this thread.